# How to stop inotify from monitoring a directory?

Tags: inotify

I've ended up in a situation where a directory is being monitored, apparently by inotify, to trigger a process that doesn't exist.

I simply want to stop inotify from monitoring the directory, but after searching and [reading the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) I can't find how to do this. The manual mentions `inotify_rm_watch` but running this, or `int inotify_rm_watch`, or `inotify`, are all not recognised from the command line.

The directory is still monitored after rebooting the system, so it's not as simple as just killing a process.

How do I permanently stop a directory being monitored by inotify? Is there some inotify config file that lists what is monitored that I should remove it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inotify_rm_watch is a programing interface that needs to be called from same process that called inotify_add_watch in first place.

Inotify is used by programs to react to file changes. To stop it from happening you have to stop the specific program using inotify. But in most cases you probably don't want to stop programs from watching for file changes because it is part of intended behavior for them.

You can list all programs using inotify with following shell command:

```
ps -p $(find /proc/*/fd/* -type l -lname 'anon_inode:inotify' -print 2> /dev/null | sed -e 's/^\/proc\/\([0-9]*\)\/.*/\1/')
```

Answer (score 4):

`inotify` watches are NOT preserved past the termination of the process that added the watch, let alone reboots. `inotify_rm_watch` is not a command-line utility, but a function meant to be called by the process that owns the watch.

If the directory is being monitored, it's because there's a process running that is monitoring it. Stop running that process, and the directory will no longer be monitored.